# How to highlight or change fore color of specific length in text box?

Tags: c#, vb.net, textbox

I want to select specific length in my textbox by this code.

```
For Each line In roboCmd.frmMain_txtCode.Lines ' It's a textbox object
    txt.SelectionStart() = 10
    txt.SelectionLength() = line.length ' line.length > 10
Next
```

It's not working at all. Am I using a wrong code?

How to change the fore color of selected string in that text box by the way?

Thanks for any responses.

Comment: You have two SelectionStart's .  Are trying to select all of the text from 10 to the end of the text?  Post an example string and the characters you are trying to select.

Comment: Oh so sorry. My bad! That was a typo mistake

Comment: Your question is not clear. You wish to select 10 characters max? Starting from 0?

Comment: What type is "frmMain_txtCode" object? I suppose it is TextBox. Also what is "txt"? Is it some other textbox in your form? Please elaborate.

Comment: Also your code will not build in the first place because you are trying to assign a value to a method (as per your code). Maybe you are trying something like txt.SelectionStart = 10 etc but not sure.

Comment: @Dayan actually  I want to select characters starting from index number 10 with the length of line.length

Comment: @samar yes it is textbox. Sorry if didn't mentioned it in my question. I've just edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Actually what I mean is to select the string with 10 length in txt.

**To select from beginning of text to 10 characters:**

```
txt.Focus()
txt.SelectionStart = 0
txt.SelectionLength = 10
```

**To select from 10 characters, until the end of text:**

```
txt.Focus()
txt.SelectionStart = 10
txt.SelectionLength = line.Length
```

If you wish to highlight text and change the color then upgrade to a `RichTextbox` Control instead of the plain/basic `Textbox`.

```
  txtRichTextbox.Select(10, txtRichTextbox.Text.Length)
  txtRichTextbox.SelectionColor = Color.Red
```

Comment: I've tried this way but still not selected. I tried to give it different values but it's not working

Comment: @EmPlusPlus I forgot to add the Focus to the textbox you wish to Highlight text from. Check my update, it will work this time.

Comment: thanks it works. Now do you know how can change the forecolor of this selected string?

Comment: @EmPlusPlus You will need to move from a simple `textbox` to a `RichTextBox` to support this. I will assume you do, check my updated answer in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean something like this:

```
txt.SelectionStart = 10
txt.SelectionLength = line.length - 10
```

Comment: No. Actually what I mean is to select the string with 10 length in txt . i think what u said is for disselect it